# How to get Prometheus metrics from Sonarqube kubernetes pod?

Tags: sonarqube, prometheus

I am running Sonarqube in Kubernetes and I want to get metrics of Sonarqube pod to Prometheus. I added prometheus.io/scrape: "true" in the service of sonarqube and able to see the endpoint in the Prometheus dashboard but it's showing DOWN status, though my pod is up and running.

Endpoint: http://sonar_ip:9000/metrics. I don't think Sonarqube exposes metrics on /metrics path because executing 'curl http://sonar_ip:9000/metrics' not showing metrics list. Does Sonarqube pod exposes any Prometheus metrics and if yes then on what path? Let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: Error in Prometheus dashboard for Sonarqube service endpoint: 'no token found'

Comment: So did you provide a use token? See [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Web+API)

Comment: Nope. I guess Sonarqube doesn't expose metrics on /metrics. I found this helpful: https://github.com/dmeiners88/sonarqube-prometheus-exporter. Downloaded exporter and moved it to pod $SONARQUBE_HOME/extensions/plugins and added prometheus.io/path: /api/prometheus/metrics as annotation in the service file and now it started showing metrics. For now, it's working but have to debug more.

Answer (score 2):

SonarQube 9.3 has added inbuilt support for Prometheus monitoring for all the editions
https://www.sonarqube.org/sonarqube-9-3/
Follow latest docs on same -
https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/monitoring/

```
Prometheus monitors your SonarQube instance by collecting metrics from the /api/monitoring/metrics endpoint. 
Results are returned in OpenMetrics text format. 
See Prometheus' documentation on Exposition Formats for more information on the OpenMetrics text format.
```

It requires auth in any of below way -

- **Authorization:Bearer xxxx header:** You can use a bearer token during database upgrade and when SonarQube is fully operational. Define the bearer token in the sonar.properties file using the sonar.web.systemPasscode property.
- **X-Sonar-Passcode: xxxxx header:** You can use X-Sonar-passcode during database upgrade and when SonarQube is fully operational. Define X-Sonar-passcode in the sonar.properties file using the sonar.web.systemPasscode property.
- **username:password and JWT token:** When SonarQube is fully operational, system admins logged in with local or delegated authentication can access the endpoint.